# New to Structure Map - Getting StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily

Tags: asp.net, structuremap

Am trying out structuremap for the first time and am getting the following compiler error,

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Super.SuperCore.Core.DataAccess.IPersonRepository, Super.SuperCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

The place where am calling the interface:

```
        private IPersonRepository _iPersonRepository;

        public void Init() {
            _iPersonRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPersonRepository>();
        }
```

My Interface Declaration:

```
[PluginFamily("Default")]
    public interface IPersonRepository
    {
        List<string> getAllNames();
    }
```

My StructureMap.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StructureMap>
<Assembly Name="Super.SuperWeb" />
<Assembly Name="Super.SuperCore" />
</StructureMap>
```

Can anyone point out where exactly am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that's not a compiler error, that's an exception, there is a very large difference, I won't go into that though.

In your configuration, you appear to be mixing and matching configuration methods.  I typically pick one and stick to it.  Here's the [documentation](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm#section7)

If you want to go the attribute route, you have to [tell SM to scan for classes with attributes](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/UsingAttributes.htm)

If you want to go the xml route, make sure your structuremap.config is getting copied to the folder with the exe.  I don't think you should have to, but you can explicitly load from the xml config like this

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddConfigurationFromXmlFile("StructureMap.config");
            });
```

If you want something that is strongly typed and compiler checked, try the registry dsl, it's the more modern configuration mechanism.